# How can I unit test a promise chain with Karma?

Tags: javascript, promise, karma-runner

My controller code has:

```
        save: function () {
            var that = this;
            patientCache.saveCurrentPatient().then(function(){
                return adherenceCache.updateAdherenceSchedule(that.model.patientId)
            }).then(function () {
                that.buildAdherenceUrl();
            });
        },
```

I want to test `patientCache.saveCurrentPatient()`, `adherenceCache.updateAdherenceSchedule` and `that.buildAdherenceUrl` are called.

This is my test:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  module('mapApp');

  return inject(function($injector) {
    var $controller, $rootScope;
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

    scope = $rootScope.$new()
    $modalMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('$modal', ['open']);
    adherenceCacheMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('adherenceCache', ['getAdherenceSchedule']);
    patientCacheMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('patientCache', ['saveCurrentPatient']);

    $controller('PatientAdherenceController', {
        $scope: scope,
        $modal: $modalMock,
        adherenceCache: adherenceCacheMock,
        patientCache: patientCacheMock
    });
    return scope.$digest();

  });
});


fit('should save the patient and update the adherence schedule on save', function() {
    scope.save();

    expect(patientCacheMock.saveCurrentPatient).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However, I get an error:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'patientCache.model.currentPatient')`

Comment: What are you running Karma on top of? Mocha? Jasmine?

Comment: I'm running it on Jasmine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I am missing something, but `jasmine.createSpyObj` makes new spies with no implementations whatsoever attached to them. What you want instead is a spy which calls through to the original function, since your promise chain assumes `patientCache.saveCurrentPatient` exists. Try setting up your spies with the `spyOn(obj, 'patientCache').and.callThrough()` syntax. Note that in order to do this, you will need to embed your methods to test in an object `obj`:

```
var obj = {
  patientCache: patientCache // where patientCache is the actual service
}
```

Of course if you do want to mock out these services you can inject spies that have fake implementation attached instead… use Jasmine's `and.returnValue` or `and.callFake`.

Comment: How do I load the actual `patientCache` service?

Comment: You're already loading real services using `$injector` — follow the same format. `patientCache = $injector.get('patientCache')`